# Custom wordpress URL to GET variables from an Email campaign

Tags: wordpress, email, url, variables

My users receive emails where they need to click on a link.
URLs in the emails looks like:

```
http://www.mywordpresssite.com/verifyvote?email=aa@aaa.com&rand=ss1dko33xj
```

My question is: how can I create a wordpress function that can `GET` that action plus reading all variables in the URL?

Also: Is it true that all wordpress URL need actual page/posts? Can't I just register a custom permalink and add something in the **`functions.php`**?

Answer (score 0):

you have to simply check that is there set any $_GET['email'], put this code on starting of page on which you want to apply some action

```
if(isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['rand'])){
  // do this
}else{
 // do this
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I know that, but do I have to create a page if I want to use the "verifyvote" permalink? Can't I just register a permalink and add this custom function if that permalink gets accessed?

Comment: no you dont register permalink coz it will be different per your mail, you can pass permalink with your url and then you can get same one, and thn you can process over that, you can write above code in same file , but before that you have to check all time that $_GET[] is set or not.